# Setting up a multi-broker cluster (kafka quickstart)

Tags: properties-file

I am trying to follow QUICKSTART in Apache Kafka homepage.

In Step 6: Setting up a multi-broker cluster,  it says " edit the server properties"

config/server-1:properties:

```
   broker.id=1
   listeners = PLAINTEXT://:9093
   logs.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-1
```

My question is :

Do I use vi editor to edit?   if yes,  I just change those 'broker', 'listeners','logs.dirs' items' values as above?

[image: kafka QUICKSTART server-1.properties edit]

Comment: Yes that is exactly what you have to do. Which editor you choose is up to you. But even vi should be able to do the job :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whichever tool you prefer, it needs to be able to change values and save the file. You could use `sed` if you really wanted to (like some Docker containers might do... On that note, you could even just use Docker Compose to start two Kafka containers side by side)

But, as the docs point out, those three properties should be unique across all brokers on a single machine, and all others can remain unchanged.

I would like to point out that having two broker processes on one machine, sharing a single disk, is not a good idea. You'd get better performance with a larger heap space on that one server

Comment: I'm just curious. How did you make the image appear as above?  When I did it, it only showed a link, not the image.